# HERE Data Inspector doesn't shows the base map

Tags: here-api, here-olp

I created a versioned layer in a catalog and published GeoJSON data to it. And I checked it from "Inspect" tab in the layer page in Workspace, but the base map(typically HERE OMV Plus) isn't shown and I can't find out the published partition. Why no base map is shown?[image]

Comment: Hi, Could you please tell us are you still having issue in base map ?

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport Yes, I still have same problem.